# what is the right way to model a "default" row in a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

== THE SCENARIO ==

We have a normal run-of-the-mill countries table.

Some new tables are being proposed that would hold rows representing settings of various kinds.

A settings table would need an FK to countries because many of the settings would be country specific.

However, some settings are considered defaults - so, not all the settings are country specific. You could think of them as a global settings or fallback settings.

One such table could look something like this:

```
 WidgetSettings
 -------------
 (PK, FK) widgetsetting_code char(8) not NULL
 (PK, FK) country_code char(2) not NULL
 SettingValue int not NULL
```

Some ideas proposed so far:

*(1) "Represent the default settings with NULL for country_code."*

No-can-do: country_code participates in the PK so we can't get away with using NULL.

*(2) "Introduce a dummy default "global" country into our countries table".*

Well, this just seems wrong to me, to pollute our countries table for this purpose. Has any one seen this as a good practice?

[EDIT] To expand a bit here, other tables currently point to countries and they need to continue to point to true country codes and not ever accidently point to to "global".

*(3) "Make a kind of Regions indexed view that unions all the countries plus the global row."*

This is where we are right now, but as an FK contraint is not possible here, we resorted to enforcing it with a trigger. Not so happy with this, especially if an alternative modeling could be found that would let us use proper FK contraints.

*(4) "Make a kind of Regions super table that contains all the countries plus the global row."*

Considering switching towards this but not liking the maintenance issue it introduces to keep it in sync with the real countries table.

---

I just have a nagging feeling there is a better way out there to represent this that we are overlooking.

Comment: Another option:  Add a surrogate PK to the WidgetSetting table and allow country_code to be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If these settings tables are not, themselves, the targets of any foreign key references<sup>1</sup>, I'd choose the `NULL` route. We can still enforce a key constraint on the table, just using a `UNIQUE` constraint rather than a `PRIMARY KEY` one:

```
create table WidgetSettings (
    widgetsetting_code char(8) not NULL,
    country_code char(2) NULL,
    SettingValue int not NULL,
    constraint PK_WidgetSettings UNIQUE (widgetsetting,country_code),
    /* TODO - FK constraints */
)
```

Primary key constraints elevate one key as being more important than others but it's not absolutely required for every table to have one (requiring a table to have at least one *key* is good, insisting that it must have a primary key, in SQL terms, is not so absolutely good).

---

<sup>1</sup>The issue here being that a reference *to* the global setting value will not be enforced by SQL Server since `NULL`s in *any* foreign key column allow the constraint to not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second option makes a lot of sense.  Call the new country something like "world", "terra", "earth", "gaia", or the like.

You don't really have a "country" table.  You have a table that supports regional settings.  You may find that continents are useful as a grouping.  Or linguistic areas.  Or time zones.  Or currency areas.  I think you are being too restrictive in the definition of "country".

Comment: Good point in some cases its better to go for "region" or even "community". Think of Switzerland with its four distinct language and cultural groupings, or Malaysia with its three distinct ethnic groupings each having different language, religious and dietary preferences but no particular geographical separation.

Comment: Hmm - but  the problem with going with the 2nd option is that all other current tables that depend on Countries (that is they want *true* countries and nothing but countries) could now, by error, accidently point to the dummy "global" row, wouldn't you agree? For this reason I'm reluctant to alter the *pure* countries table. I guess then that leaves option #4.

Answer (score 0):

So the basic structure should be something like:--

```
Country -----> CountryXpreference -------> Preference
```

Within the structure the choice is either fill out all the possible permutations in the CountryXprefernce relationship table.

Or define a special "everywhere" country with the default preferences in CountryXPreference and define only the exceptions in the CountryXpreference for the "real" countries.

I personally would go for the first option as experience tells me that in the long term there will be more exceptions than defaults. Also maintaining this is not so hard you have 200 odd countries so just populate everything with the defaults and let your business users log in and update the countries needing  an exception.

When you get a new country you can cook up some simple SQL to copy the most alike country.